# Bootstrap 5 in angular project via angular.json file

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I built a new angular project using the cli

```
ng new memmory-game
```

I want to use bootstrap and because I know that bootstrap 5 has dropped the jQuery dependency, I'm opting to not use something like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

The installed bootstrap via npm as well as popperjs

Here is my package.json file so you can see my dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

You can see that I actually installed both `popper.js` and `popperjs/core` because I wasn't actually sure which one I needed.

In `app.component.html` I put some bootstrap components.

Without styles, it looks like this.

[image: unstyled components]

If I use `@import` in `styles.scss` in the root of my project, everything works.

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

[image: styled components]

These look correct but still don't quite work correctly. The tooltip doesn't display and the dropdown doesn't work.

If I include the bootstrap javascript file via cdn in the index.html file, the dropdown starts working.

[image: cdnjavascript]

[image: dropdownworking]

But say I want to move the javascript and the css into the angular.json file like a lot of tutorials recommend.

I've removed the cdn from the `index.html` file and I've removed the import from the `styles.scss` file and moved them into `angular.json` like so.
[image: styles in json file]

but suddenly my page is broken again. All of the styles are gone and the drop-down doesn't work. I've tried updating the path in the angular.json file to remove the `./` but that doesn't help.

[image: withoutPeriod]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there a reason why my angular.json file isn't loading my styles and scripts like expected? Should I even bother with this or is loading things in via my scss file and from a script cdn loaded via the html fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right adding the resources in the `angular.json` file.

But, looks like you're importing the resources in the wrong place.

You need to import styles and scripts in the `build` section of the `angular.json` which is typically a little higher in the file.

Like this:
(*please, ignore the "**", are just to highlight the sections*)

```
"architect": {
        **"build": {**
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/website",
            "index": "projects/website/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/website/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/website/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/website/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/website/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/website/src/assets",
              "projects/website/src/.htaccess"
            ],
            **"styles": [**
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "projects/website/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            **"scripts": [**
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ],
```

You will still need to import these resources in the test section if you're planning to do unit/e2e testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it manually like that, you'd need to put popper into your angular.json's scripts array as well (above bootstrap.js I believe).

But I wouldn't do it manually like that.  I would just use ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.  It will setup everything for you.  Undo all your pending changes first, or start with a new project.

Comment: I don't think that's true. According to this page, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/
popper.js is included in the bundle.min file

Comment: Actually, @onTheInternet is right for regular bootstrap.  But since you're using ng-bootstrap, you should just follow the instructions here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home, which is the ng-add method.

Comment: We use ng-bootstrap, and our scripts array in angular.json is empty.